# JS cannot set textfont

Tags: javascript, fonts

I'm trying to set the font on a piece of text. I'm relatively new to JavaScript so please have a bit of patience with this. This is what I have so far:

```
    newFont.load().then(function(loaded_face) {
      // use font here

      let help = text(' Instructions ',
      950, 200, 300, 300);
      help.textFont(newFont);
      console.log("Success");
  
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  
  });
```

In the Pre-Load function, called on the first entrance to the website I have:

```
 newFont= new FontFace('newFont', 'url(fonts/newFont.otf)');
```

I get no errors when I load it in, so I'm stumped

Comment: You can't assing a font to a JS string. What are `text` and `help.textFont` doing?

Comment: @Teemu text is adding some text onto the webpage at those x,y coordinates with the other set of numbers being the size of the textbox.
What I thought help.textFont would do is set the font of the text that was just spawned in, to the desired font defined at the top

Comment: You never use the loaded font, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace/FontFace